# React Native - Flex Layout - text overflow issue

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have the following layout within a RN View:

[image]

The buttons on the left have a dynamic width applied to a surrounding wrapper view - as based on state there could be 1, 2 or 3 buttons.  the width is applied by conditional styles.  My issue is - whatever i do I cannot get the description box to wrap - the text wrapper takes on the full width of the screen rather than its available remaining width..

**Code:**

**Here is the code structure:**

```
<View
  style={[FormStyles.prRowStrip, { width: "100%", flexGrow: 0, flexWrap: 0 }]}
>
  <View style={RP_Styles.btnRow}>
    <View
      style={[
        returnHeader_full() && RP_Styles.btnWrap,
        returnHeader_two() && RP_Styles.btnWrap_two,
        returnHeader_one() && RP_Styles.btnWrap_one
      ]}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[
          RP_Styles.smlBtnWrap,
          !hasSiteGuide() && HomeStyles.checkedInHide
        ]}
        onPress={() => this.openDocument(this.state.locationSiteGuidePdf)}
      >
        <Image
          style={RP_Styles.homeSegmentImg}
          source={require("../images/icons/ico_site_guide.png")}
        />
        <Text style={RP_Styles.homeSegmentText}>Guide</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[
          RP_Styles.smlBtnWrap,
          !hasInventoryItems() && HomeStyles.checkedInHide
        ]}
        onPress={toggleELModal}
      >
        <Image
          style={RP_Styles.homeSegmentImg}
          source={require("../images/icons/ico_equip_guide.png")}
        />
        <Text style={RP_Styles.homeSegmentText}>Equip</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity style={RP_Styles.smlBtnWrap} onPress={toggleIssueModal}>
        <Image
          style={RP_Styles.homeSegmentImg}
          source={require("../images/icons/ico_issue_b.png")}
        />
        <Text style={RP_Styles.homeSegmentText}>Issue</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    <View style={RP_Styles.txtBlock}>
      <Text style={[RP_Styles.locBlockTxt]}>
        Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
        enim ad minim veniam
        {this.state.currentMarkerName} - {this.state.currentMarkerDescription}
      </Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

Heres the relevant applied styles currently:

```
const RP_Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  txtBlock: {
    backgroundColor:'red',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  locBlockTxt: {
    fontSize: 15,
    color: '#f79431',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    fontWeight: '500',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  btnRow: {
    paddingTop: 4,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  btnWrap: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '180',
  },
  btnWrap_two: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexGrow:0,
    flexShrink:0,
    width:120,
  },
  btnWrap_one: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexGrow:0,
    flexShrink:0,
    width:60,
  },
  flRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingHorizontal: 6,
    paddingTop: 12,

    marginVertical: 6,
  },
  firstRow: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  
)}
const Form_Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  prRowStrip: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)',
    marginVertical: 3,
    paddingVertical: 4,
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
  },
}
```

as you see there a few inline styles where i've tried adding various style classes - but this is where its at at the mo.  Any help would be great-fully received!

Comment: try giving this style flex:1

 ,txtBlock: {
     flex:1,
    backgroundColor:'red',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },

this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @NitinSidhu I had tried a flex1 - but this with a combo of a parent change (removing the margin vertical) worked for some reason!?  cheers anyway.